# Using sj:select with s:checkboxlist

Tags: jquery, struts2, controller, checkboxlist, checked

So I have trouble trying to use any of these two elements for different reasons. First I'll describe what happens with the `s:checkboxlist`.

When the value on the `sj:select` changes I want to populate a list on my controller to use on my `s:checkboxlist`, do I have to use javascript? My initial guess was to call a javascript function on the `sj:select onchange=""` parameter, then on the javascript function refresh the `s:checkboxlist` so it populates using the new list.

For example if I have something like on my `sj:select`:

```
<s:url id="urlGetNewList"
    action="mycontroller!getNewList" />
<sj:select href="%{urlGetNewList}" id="myselect"
    onChangeTopics="reloadList"
    onCompleteTopics="reloadList"
    name="model.idType" list="types"
    listKey="idType" listValue="nameType"
    emptyOption="false" headerKey="-1"
    headerValue="select a value"
    formIds="frmMyForm" />
```

and on my `s:checkboxlist` I have :

```
<s:checkboxlist name="arrayOfIds" list="idsType"
                listKey="id" listValue="name"
                theme="vertical-checkbox" />
```

So my `s:select` gets populated from a list called types, when the value on the `sj:select` changes I call a function on my controller named `getNewList`, that will change the list that uses my checkboxlist, but how can refresh the checkboxlist.

You can notice I could solve this by using a `sj:checkboxlist`, I know it works, but if I do that then when I try to load the checkbox that are checked through the Integer array `idsType`, the checkboxes won't get checked. For example if I have an Integer array like this:

```
idsType = { 2, 3 }
```

and I have a list `arrayOfIds` with 5 elements, then when I use the `s:checkboxlist`, 5 checkboxes will be shown and the second and third checkbox will be checked.

But if I do this using `sj:checkboxlist`, then only the first checkbox will be checked and also the checkboxes will change dinamically according to the `sj:select` value, which won't happen when I use a `s:checkboxlist`.

I'm really lost as to how can I solve this issue, if anybody can help it will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question, of course you'd need to use JavaScript to update the checkbox list--the standard `<s:checkboxlist>` is completely unaware of Ajax. You would need to do it manually by binding to the topic published by the `sj:select`.

The plugin wiki (assuming this is the plugin you're using, there are actually a few) has a page discussing [how to handle JSON results in a topic](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/JsonResult).

The `<sj:checkboxlist>` can reload by listening to topics; there should be no issue handling multiple items in the list; you may need to provide additional details regarding what you tried, and what went wrong (if anything, for example, check the JavaScript console).

Comment: for the sj:checkboxlist I use '<sj:checkboxlist href="%{urlGetIdsType}"
      id="ids" list="idsType" name="arraysOfIds"
       listKey="id" listValue="name"
      buttonset="false" reloadTopics="reloadList"
      deferredLoading="true" formIds="frmMyForm"
      loadingText="Loading" />
    </div>' but this will fail to check the checkboxes, as I said before I'm using an Integer array which contains which checkboxes are checked, but that works on the s:checkboxlist but won't work on the sj:checkboxlist, how can I check them?

Comment: I checked your link and that's what I'm looking for, but I don't know how to reload the s:checkboxlist using the new list, is there a function to reload a single component? or what should I do to reload that specific component?